# How do close votes look like?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Might be a dumb question, but how does a question that acquired close votes look like, from the askers perspective?

Are the specific close reasons visible, or does the asker of the question just see the `close (1)` that I see? How obvious is it that a question has close votes? How does it look if there are votes on different reasons? Is the asker actively notified about the vote?

I always asked that myself, but I don't create enough <strike>bad</strike> close worthy questions to have experienced this first hand.

I would prefer a screenshot over a close vote ;-)

Comment: We could close this for you ... ;)

Comment: @Bart He has VTC privs already though (even on meta, as the rep carries over).  We'd have to get a mod to suspend his account, *then* vote to close his question.  Or just mass downvote, but that would be a *lot* of downvotes (24,490 to be precise, which would require 613 people using all 40 of their daily votes on his account, somehow without tripping the serial voting script).

Comment: Sounds like a plan @Servy

Comment: Should I start a hundred bounties so it gets easier for you?

Answer (score 6):

There is [a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to view close votes on your own question.  If you don't have it, then you have no idea the votes are there.  If you do, then you can see the close votes but not cast any.  It looks more or less like what the close vote dialog looks like if you've already cast a close vote.

Of course, if you have the rep to vote to close, then you see exactly what every other user with that privilege sees, with respect to the close functionality.

There is one exception though; if there is even one vote to close as a duplicate then only the question author will see a banner similar to what is shown when a question is actually closed as a duplicate, informing them of the possible duplicate question and explaining how to proceed.  Note that this is separate from the "possible duplicate" comment that is automatically posted.

Comment: So it's basically just the small `close (1)` and not a big box of "your question might be closed because ...".

Comment: See edit, once exception (duplicates).  Other than that, yes.