# Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a more general question, when none of the answers to the broader question apply?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently asked a question regarding work-arounds to a limitation in a popular stylesheet language, which essentially boiled down to:

> How do I work around X limitation in this stylesheet language in specific case Z?

Shortly thereafter, someone suggested that my question might be a duplicate of another question which essentially boiled down to:

> How do I work around X limitation in this stylesheet language?

Which was not a question I was previously aware of, and pretty clearly related to my problem. After looking through that question for a solution to my problem though, I discovered that none of the answers to that more general question were applicable to specific case Z.

Furthermore, given the quality and variety of answers on the broader question, the fact that none of them would work in specific case Z is leading me to suspect that no workaround exists for my specific case.

What should I do? Should I close my question as a duplicate of the more general one, even though none of the answers to that question address my problem? Or should I leave my question open in hope that someone will know of a solution which works in specific case Z?

---

Note that I phrased this meta question in such a way as to promote answers which address the general problem, not my question in particular. The actual question I asked is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29525736/1157054), and the proposed duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840918/removing-duplicate-css-with-sass-media-and-extend). Please let me know if you think my generalization of the problem is leaving out any crucial details which might affect the answer in my specific case.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not)

Comment: @gnat Really? How? This question is asking whether specific questions should be closed as duplicates of their more general counterparts (even when the existing answers to the more general question don't apply the specific one), whereas that question is asking what to do when someone votes to close a question as a duplicate when it is clearly not. Are you saying the answer to the title question here is "No"?

Comment: [How to oppose questions marked as duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252691/how-to-oppose-questions-marked-as-duplicate) -> [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue)

Comment: Just to clarify for everyone, you feel that "I don't feel like editing the open source library I am using so that I can make this work as directed in the original question" is justification for why your question is not a duplicate?

Comment: @cimmanon Sure you can always fork the library and change the source, but there are a number of reasons why that's undesirable. After creating a fork you have to maintain it, making it more difficult to upgrade to a newer version of the library in the future. The point is: there are different requirements leading to potentially different answers, so yes that might justify a separate question.

Comment: See also  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130326/unclear-policy-for-duplication-by-inclusion

Comment: @Raedwald That question is pretty outdated, but is definitely very similar to the question I'm asking here. Good find. (Doesn't look like there's really a definitive answer there though, unfortunately.)

Comment: @gnat Now I'm confused. How is [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/1157054) related to either of those questions, other than that they're all about close/reopen votes? Or are you trying to say my question isn't a duplicate, and I should "oppose the duplicate vote" and then "reopen if it gets closed"? I'm confused.

Comment: in your case, this question explains what to expect in case if it gets closed - namely that "de-duplicating edit" made prior to closure won't push it into queue. If (_if_) this happens, and if you think your prior edit explains the difference clearly enough, you could probably consider inserting a line like "for the reasons laid out below, answers in <link to dupe> do _not_ and can _not_ cover the case asked about here:" -- to make it easier for reopen reviewers to see where exactly to look for explanation

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277950/is-a-question-a-duplicate-if-the-duplicate-has-no-answers

Comment: @cimmanon That question seems to be asking specifically about questions on meta, not the main site.

Answer (score 7):

> Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a more general question,
>   when **none of the answers to the broader question apply**?

A dupe is not defined by an answer for your question "not being present" on the other, a dupe is specifically if answers do "*or could potentially*" answer your question.

There's sometimes more to defining a dupe, but essentially:

- If a legitimate answer could be applied to the supposed duped
  question (original one) and it would also be an adequate answer for
  the newer question, then newer question is a dupe

Even if answers on the duped question do not answer the new question, if an answer *can* be applied to the duped question which would answer the newer question then it is a dupe.

While it's frustrating that older answers can be dead and gone, that does not stop a new question being a duplicate. We cannot duplicate questions just because they need new/fresh/more activity or views.

For that we can comment, or add a bounty.

> Should I close my question as a duplicate of the more general one,
>   even though **none of the answers to that question address my problem**?

Again, it's about *potential* to answer your question, not if it already does or not.
So you should only close yours if the other question does or *could possibly* answer your question.

However, it sounds like in your scenario, with "in specific case Z", then the older question is not likely to answer the newer one.

The sites are filled with questions which are "very similar" and are about the same basic topics, and tags are re-used every day, neither of those things by their own merits alone defines a dupe.

With that said:

cimmanon wrote:

> The fact that neither of those options are viable for your situation
>   is irrelevant: those are the only options that exist. If you don't
>   like them, I suggest you take your complaint to the maintainers of
>   Sass (or Bootstrap).

If this *is* the case, then your question *has* been answered and marking as a dupe would be prudent, as you have your answer *and* a dupe link will likely take other users to "the answer(s)" to their question too.

However, and with all respect to cimmanon, that is but one user's opinion, and the point of asking questions is to get a large audience.

Perhaps someone else *can* answer your question specifically to your particular scenario, and their answer would not "fit" in the other question as an acceptable answer for that question.

---

So:
Is it possible to answer the suspected duped question adequately for that question alone, on scope and topic, and it would also answer your question?

If no, then yours is not a dupe.

(Being too localised, or other problems, is another matter)

Comment: I think by definition, answers to a general question could always "potentially" answer a more narrowly focused one. That doesn't mean it's likely though. Many times the obvious solution to a broader problem won't fit a more narrow case, as in the example of my question. Anyway, would I be correct in assuming that you believe that, in general, questions which are subsets of a broader question should always be closed as a duplicate of the general one?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Except you don't have such a case.  You have a case of "I don't want to modify the original" combined with "I don't want to use JavaScript".

Comment: @cimmanon It's certainly possible my requirements are unrealistic given the constraints of the language. I don't know whether that's the case though, which is why I asked the question in the first place. If "that's not possible" turns out to be the answer, then I'm willing to accept that, even if it's not the answer I want to hear. And yes, my question has more narrow requirements than the proposed duplicate, which is exactly the case I described.

Comment: If the answer is "for specific situation Z, it is not possible", then this question is unique and has a specific answer for a specific situation. I feel we're missing the point of SO if questions are going to get marked as a dupe simply because a very broad question "could potentially answer" another question. It's probably better practice to comment the link, ask if that addresses their issue, and ask the OP to clarify if necessary, rather than knee-jerking a dupe and close - which typically discourages others from participating in the discussion and is beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

Two things here:

1. **Does the suggested duplicate answer your question?** If it does, then yes, it would make sense to close your question as a duplicate of it.
2. If it doesn't, **you must edit your question** to further prove that these two things are not related.

My gut tells me that someone may have pulled the trigger a little too early when they read this:

> Essentially my problem is similar to Removing duplicate CSS with SASS @media and @extend [...]

Comment: That statement was added after the duplicate was suggested, in an attempt for me to do exactly what you said in point #2.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the question to discuss the solutions presented in the proposed duplicate and explain why they do not solve your specific problem.  This distinguishes the question and makes yours not a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Makes sense. So I guess in my case is that final paragraph I added to my question was not sufficient to distinguish the question? I guess I'll update it to address the answers to the proposed duplicate more directly.

Comment: @Ajedi32 since as of now your question is _not_ (yet) closed, it is worth noting that you as the asker will see [duplicate banner](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254095/839601) until either it's closed or all close votes/flags [age away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/165773). FWIW that banner is not shown to other users, you can check this by trying to see your question when logged out

Comment: @gnat Right, I'm aware of that. Thanks for the reminder. Speaking of which, wasn't there a feature request a while back asking for the message in that banner to be more clear about who can see it? I think there was, but I can't find that post now...

Comment: @Ajedi32 [Can we clarify to the OP that their question is not yet closed and the duplicates are only suggestions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/165773) (...says [meta-tag:status-completed] but given your question I'd rather say [meta-tag:status-not-quite-there])

Comment: @gnat Yeah that's the one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the specific question, you posted this comment:

> Specifically, work-arounds which don't use JavaScript or require me to modify the definition of the class I'm extending. Apparently no such workarounds exist, but the answers to the other question don't say that, because in the scope of that question there are applicable workarounds.

Because all of the answers in the original question require modifications to the original source, you feel that your question is *not* a duplicate because you don't want to make the necessary modifications to make it work.  If there *was* an option where making modifications was unnecessary *someone would have posted it as an answer to the original question*.

> Apparently no such workarounds exist, but the answers to the other question don't say that, because in the scope of that question there are applicable workarounds.

**Sometimes, the absence of an answer *is* the answer** (or the lack of additional options can mean that there *are no additional options available at this point in time*).  No one should have to outright say "All of the options I can think of have already been posted!  There are no other options!  Tough titties if you need one!"

It should be noted that the answer you already received is an imitation of one found in the original question.

Comment: "Sometimes, the absence of an answer is the answer" True that is a good point. I actually alluded to this in my question here on meta. While it may be a form of answer to some extent though, you have to admit it's not a very definite one...