# Are general questions appropriate as duplicates to specific questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have been seeing a lot of duplicates being marked recently where the question may have a particular error/problem and gets marked as a duplicate to a question that has general answers which may be used to solve the problem.

For example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000383/javascript-regular-expression-6) question. The user asks about a particular regex match he/she is trying to create, shows the attempts he has made and is looking for debugging help to find why it's not matching correctly. It gets quickly marked as a duplicate to "Learning Regular Expressions."

I understand that perhaps the answer may be found in another question. Learning regular expressions would help to solve a regular expression bug, but is that really the same a duplicate? It almost seems like saying, "you are not very good at x, why don't you go learn x." Is that the purpose of Q/A? (Note: this was not my question, nor do I have any interest in its reception. I am just curious what the policy is and why.)

Comment: give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: We probably have a dupe for your question :)

Comment: @Stijn I agree with that sentiment. I am not suggesting just giving them the solution point blank. Why not point to where they are misinterpreting the code? Isn't that exactly what SO is for?

Comment: I think the problem is that answering all regex questions individually doesn't scale very well, and this is the best thing the community has to offer to still help the asker somewhat.

Comment: @Servy Are you sure that's a good duplicate?

Comment: @mhatch No, SO is not here to be a personal tutor to someone and hold their hand.  It's here to be a reference source for answers to questions in such a way that the information will be applicable to others with the same problem.

Comment: @Stijn Do you have a better one?  It seems to answer the question he has.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I focussed too much on the question being asked, but the answer applies here indeed.

Comment: I think this answer is the best fit http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289912/4084574

Comment: I'm just impressed people were able to close that before 53 people answered it...

Comment: It is a "halp, it doesn't work" question without a good example of a string that does not work.   Dumb way to ask for help, isn't it?  Just not much point in second-guessing it, life's too short.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think that is because it was ambiguous exactly what the OP wanted.